# how to stay in the same page of primefaces datatable after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Actually as exactly the title of this question states, i want to stay on the same page after ajax update of the datatable, i'm using lazyloading, when i paginate to x page and i click refresh button which basically updates the datatble component after executing a query, the datatable goes back to the first page automatically, is this the normal behaviour or i'm missing something ?

```
 <p:dataTable id="tabexam"
              lazy="true"
              paginatorPosition="bottom"
              var="exam"
              value="#{dyna.lazyModel}"
              widgetVar="examTable"
              emptyMessage="aucun résultat trouvé pour votre recherche"
              paginator="true"
              rows="#{dyna.rows}" 
              selection="#{dyna.selectedExamen}"
              rowKey="#{exam.studyUid}"
              selectionMode="single"
              rowIndexVar="indexvar"
              resizableColumns="false"  
              draggableColumns="true"
              paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">
```

Comment: What do you mean you click 'refresh' button? You mean you press F5 refresh? if you do that it re-renders the page from scratch 100% start up, so will go back to page 1.

Comment: no i mean refresh datatable.

Comment: What's the scope of your backing bean?